# coded ui object repository

Tags: automation, coded-ui-tests

I am creating a test automation script for a Internet banking application through Coded UI.
Internet banking application has various functionalities(Accounts,Fund Transfer,Cards etc). I am creating each functionality as a different coded ui project. But all these have some common functionalities like 'Launching browser','Login', etc. How can I create an object repository for these basic functions and just call it on my every projects? ( I have heard through my friend that he had done the same in UFT)

Comment: This is very broad.... you could better ask your friend to help you out if he had done such before

Comment: He knows it in UFT but not in Coded UI :(

Answer (score 0):

Vicky,

You can call your test methods just like normal methods. If you create a separate ui test project for your common functionalities, you should be able to call those methods after referencing the project and creating a new instance of the class containing your common functionality methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a separate class for login functionality and call them in your test initialize methods or assembly initialize methods , so that it is called automatically whenever you run a script.